# I have problems with cdo command monmean

Tags: cdo-climate

I´m working with CDO and I would like to get the maximum temperature from my file. The time data is different if I use the command `cdo monmax infile outfile`  and `cdo --timestat first monmax infile outfile`

If i use `cdo monmax` infile outfile the timedata is: 2021-06-15 22:30:00 and if I use `cdo --timestat first monmax infile outfile` the timedata is: 2021-06-01 00:00:00

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. `cdo --timestat first` will result in the first time step in the infile being used in the outfile, whereas not including `timestat` will just use the default time method. Why do you not expect them to be different?

Comment: hi, Robert is right, this is exactly the behaviour you expect, if you want to see how timestat_date works, I explain it at about minute=6 in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD1r12pklEo

Comment: Thanks to both of you, with your youtube video it´s already clearer to me. The thing is that I have three hours timesteps, so 22:30:00 seemed a strange result to me.

Comment: If this is why it seemed strange, it would be better to say it in the question. We are not psychic ;)

Comment: that is probably precisely the mid point of the month calculated by cdo based on the 3 hourly steps.